# Error when running created React Native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npx

I'm running the following from the command line:

`npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

...and I see the following output after the React logo:

```
                  Welcome to React Native!                
                 Learn once, write anywhere               

✖ Downloading template
error Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native@latest
error Couldn't find any versions for "@jest/types" that matches "^27.2.4"

warning react-native > @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios > xcode > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
...
yarn add v1.22.11
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Why is it complaining?

Comment: It *seems* like it's an issue with the latest version of `react-native`. If I run `yarn` against the following `package.json`, it's fine:

`{ "name": "awesometsproject", "version": "0.0.1", "dependencies": { "react": "17.0.1", "react-native": "0.64.0" } }`

...but if I change the `react-native` version to `0.65.1` I get the following error:

`Couldn't find any versions for "@jest/types" that matches "^27.2.4"`

Answer (score 1):

1. uninstall node
2. reinstall using package manager like 'homebrew'
3. try again 'npx react-native init project'

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have mistakenly written the dependency's name? Isn't it @types/jest instead? See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jest